# How to get bodyTemperature using health-kit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am trying to get the bodyTemperature in iWatch so below is the code i have written

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

    guard let type=HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyTemperature) else {
        return
    }

    let dataTypes=Set(arrayLiteral:type)

    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: dataTypes) { (success, error) in

        if success==false{
            print("Authorize Unsuccessfull ")
        }
    }
}

 @IBAction func startBtnTapped(){
      startSession()
   }


func startSession(){

    session = HKWorkoutSession(activityType: HKWorkoutActivityType.crossTraining, locationType: HKWorkoutSessionLocationType.indoor)
    session?.delegate = self
    healthStore.start(session!)
}


 func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {

    switch toState {
    case .running:
       if let query=createQuery(date){
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
    case .ended:
        workoutEnd(date)
    default:
        print("Unexpted state:\(toState)")
    }
}

func createQuery(_ startDate:Date)->HKQuery?{

    guard let type=HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyTemperature) else {
        return nil
    }

    let predicate=getPredicate()

    let query=HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: type, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sample, deletedObject, newAnchor, error) in

        print("query:\(query)")
        print("sample:\(sample)")
        print("deletedObject:\(deletedObject)")
        print("newAnchor:\(newAnchor)")

        self.updateValues(sample)
    }

    query.updateHandler={(query,sample,deletedObject,newAcnhor,error) in

        self.updateValues(sample)
    }

    return query
}
```

On execution of query every time completion block reruns 0 values. The same code is working to get the heart rate. I don't know the procedure to get the other stuff like body temperate, glucose rate, bodyFatPercentage, bodyMassIndex etc from the halthkit. Can anybody help me in this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What samples are you expecting to get? What app saved them?

Comment: @Allan I am trying to get the samples which are available in healthstore. Basically I am trying it in iWatch.

Comment: @Allan And also i wanted to know what are the things we can get using watch sensor . I did some google regarding this but not succeed please guide me in this

Comment: did u get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no body temperature sensor on the Apple Watch. Any body temperature samples in HealthKit would have been saved by an app or entered manually by the user.

Comment: Thanks for your information about sensor. above code is written to get the temperature from the healthstore dashboard. can you please tell me where i did wrong?  from above code I am not getting the sample of temperature which is stored in dashboard

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dashboard"? How was the body temperature sample added? How old is it?

Comment: In my point dashboard is health data which is in health app. I have added body temperature manually in health data.